# Fluctuating ADC readings upon changing power source

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, raspberry-pi, 4-20ma

I used the following circuit to power and measure my pressure transmitter (4-20ma) sensor and the microcontroller, when the charger and battery are connected at the same time or when i disconnect the battery i get a fluctuating readings from the connected ADC (Arduino or Raspberrypi), i only get a stable readings when the battery is the only power source.

[image: Uninterrupted power source]

Would you please explain the possible causes of this issue, and what should i do to have uninterrupted power source without affecting the measured values.

Thanks

Comment: Define Charger, CC or CV mode, ripple frequency, Battery age, ESR? ripple V. You probably need a Cap across transducer if not included.

Comment: CV charger found here: https://www.controllers4generators.com/catalog/generator_battery_chargers_power_supplies/datakom_smps_2410_generator_start_battery_charger_stabilized_power_supply_24v_10a/   , the battery is a normal 12vdc car battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxS4Wr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What kind of switch are you using that switches both charger and battery?  Beware of arcs. You only need to switch the load.

Comment: I'm using a bridge to switch between the power source automatically, and to keep the battery charged.

Comment: This method I suggest is better for low ripple and automatic charging. Your method has high R from diodes thus worse voltage regulation and your failure.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try the method you suggested and feedback here

Comment: Start by adding from either side of battery one or other or both filters should  work